# Django model field to image in static folder

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a Django model of a game with fields for a name and also a cover image that is located in the static folder of the app.

```
def game_covers_path():
    return os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, 'some_app/games/')


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    cover = models.FilePathField(path=game_covers_path, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── some_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   └── some_app
    │       ├── games
    │       │   ├── Counterstrike:\ Global\ Offensive.jpg
    ├── templates
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

But when I open the admin page I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /admin/some_app/game/add/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/some_app/games/'
```

How can I correctly reference images in the static folder of an app in the database? Also does the FilePathField check if the a file exists before saving a model? Because I tried adding random values and it saved it, but in the documentation its written that you can only choose a file that already exists...

Answer (score 0):

(too long for comment)

1. STATIC_URL is an **URL** which will be mapped to STATIC_ROOT **path** by Django in runtime, so use STATIC_ROOT to build file **path**
2. **static** files are not supposed to be dynamically modified: css, js, favicon; what you are trying to do is called **media** files in terms of Django so use to MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT instead. Also note, whereas **static** files are fine to be stored in project folder, **media** files are usually stored somewhere else. They are not part of your project/solution - they are **data**.
3. To handle properly both static and media files you must configure STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL

There are dozens of questions and answers related to Django static and media files here on SO, please have a look at them. And please take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#media-root).

Comment: I dont need dynamiclly modified files, so from what I understood in the docs I should set the STATIC_ROOT and then run collectstatic but do I need apache for local development?

Comment: No, you don't need apache for local development.

Comment: ok, so it worked for the admin page but the image is not visible in the webpage (it cant find 'localhost:8000/STATIC_ROOT...' )